# How to Play AVAudio player from Starting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

I was Created AVAudio Player, its playing perfectly,Click the play button song is playing and its shows pause button,click pause button song is paused and its shows play button,but click the play button is playing from starting onwards.i want play resume song. how to control this issue. this is my code , please check once's.

```
-(void)playAudio
{
   // [progreetimer invalidate];
   // if([audioPlayer isPlaying]==YES)`enter code here`
    if(self.isPlaying)
    {
        [self.play setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audioplayer_play.png"]
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         NSLog(@"Pausing Music");
        if (self.progreetimer) {
            [self.progreetimer invalidate];
            progreetimer =nil;
        }
        [audioPlayer pause];
        self.isPlaying = NO;
    }

    else {

        // Init audio with playback capability
    [self.play setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audioplayer_pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   // NSString *urlstr = @"http://jesusredeems.in/media/Media Advt/mp3_player/Songs/viduthalaiyin geethangal_vol1/93.Ellame Koodum.mp3";

    NSString *urlstr =@"http://www.abstractpath.com/files/audiosamples/sample.mp3";
    urlstr = [urlstr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
    audioPlayer.volume = 1.9f;
  //  [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    SongProgressBar.maximumValue = [audioPlayer duration];
    SongProgressBar.value = 0.0;
        NSLog(@"Playing music");

    //start a timer to update the time label display
    self.progreetimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self
    selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    self.progreetimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self
    selector:@selector(updateSlider) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [progreetimer fire];
    audioPlayer.delegate=self;
    [audioPlayer play];
        self.isPlaying = YES;

    }
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.SongProgressBar.minimumValue = 30;

    self.SongProgressBar.maximumValue = 30;

    [self.SongProgressBar setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbslider.png"]

                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   // [self.SongProgressBar setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_icon.png"]

                      //  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [self.SongProgressBar setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_max.png"]

                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.SongProgressBar setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_icon.png"]

                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [audioPlayer pause]; // Or pause
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [audioPlayer play];
}



- (IBAction)songprogressbar:(id)sender {
    // Fast skip the music when user scroll the UISlider
    [audioPlayer stop];
    [audioPlayer setCurrentTime:SongProgressBar.value];
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play];
}

- (IBAction)backword:(id)sender {
    if ([self.audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
        NSTimeInterval desiredTime = audioPlayer.currentTime -15.0f;
        if (desiredTime < 0) {
            audioPlayer.currentTime =0.0f;
        } else {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = desiredTime;
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {

    [self playAudio];
}
- (void)updateSlider {
    // Update the slider about the music time
    SongProgressBar.value = audioPlayer.currentTime;
}

- (void)setCurrentAudioTime:(float)value {
    [self.audioPlayer setCurrentTime:value];
}
 //Stops the timer when the music is finished
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying : (AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully : (BOOL)flag {
    // Music completed
    if (flag) {
        [progreetimer invalidate];

         NSLog(@"Finished playing the song");
    }
}

- (IBAction)forword:(id)sender {

    if ([audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
        NSTimeInterval desiredTime = audioPlayer.currentTime +15.0f;
        if (desiredTime < audioPlayer.duration) {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = desiredTime;
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)volume:(id)sender {
     audioPlayer.volume=volume.value;
}

-(NSString*)timeFormat:(float)value{

    float minutes = floor(lroundf(value)/60);
    float seconds = lroundf((value) - (minutes * 60));

    int roundedSeconds = lroundf(seconds);
    int roundedMinutes = lroundf(minutes);

    NSString *time = [[NSString alloc]
                      initWithFormat:@"%d:%02d",
                      roundedMinutes, roundedSeconds];
    return time;

}
- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer {

        self.starttimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
        [self timeFormat: ceilf(audioPlayer.currentTime)]];


        self.endtimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@", [self timeFormat: (audioPlayer.duration - ceilf(audioPlayer.currentTime))]];
    }
```

Comment: When your instance of  `AVAudioPlayer` is paused and the `playAudio ` is called you create a new instance of `AVAudioPlayer` discarding the previous one which is paused.  You should detect the play state of the `AVAudioPlayer` and start playing again when it is paused.

Comment: how to change that one?

Answer (score 1):

You should try this. see **else** part of method

```
-(void)playAudio
{
    // [progreetimer invalidate];
   // if([audioPlayer isPlaying]==YES)`enter code here`
    if(self.isPlaying)
    {
        //Code to pause audioPlayer
        [audioPlayer pause];
        self.isPlaying = NO;
    }

    else 
    {
            if(audioPlayer.url != nil && audioPlayer.duration != 0)
            {
                [audioPlayer play];
            }
            else
            {
                //Code to add new audioPlayer
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working bro. if statement not calling. can u change the code.

Comment: Did you define audioPlayer as global constant?? if not than define it as global! cause this code is working for me

Answer (score -2):

Use the following code

```
AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL error: nil];
[player prepareToPlay];
player.currentTime = 0;
[player play];
```

Comment: The question is not about how to create the `AVAudioPlayer ` and play the music, it is about pausing it an continuing playing later.

Comment: need to add player current time to zero